# Crystal Report Loop until True and Return Value

Tags: crystal-reports-2011

I have a field called "Step Number" and would like to determine the previous step. There are two tables: Work Order Step (WOS) & Route Steps (RS).

I would like to state something along these lines:

1. Take the "Step Number" and subtract 1.
2. Continue subtracting 1 until the Step Number from WOS is equal to a value in RS
3. Return the value which stopped the formula

Code I have tried:

`do ToNumber({WO3_WorkOrderOperationDetail.StepNumber})-1  while Not(ToNumber({WO3_WorkOrderOperationDetail.StepNumber})= ToNumber({WO_97_UDF_WORoutingLines.StepNumber}))`

Also have tried to do a "result" at the end, but this is not my forte and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Can you provide please further information about your Report design, some data, or any thing other.

Comment: Hi Mohamad, not sure what to provide. I can't provide data to you or the report itself.

i have two databases that this is pulling from WS and RS.